# MySQL: Getting the most counted same-value entry (statistical mode) per hour within a datetime range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+---------+----------------------+--------------+----------+
| idadata | value_r  | date_r               | idparameter  | idnode  |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+--------+
| 54620   | 66.6627  | 2014-10-16 12:01:09  |    46         |   9    |
| 54621   | 19.4953  |2014-10-16 12:01:09   |    40         |   9    |
| 54622   | 19.9384  |2014-10-16 12:01:09   |    47         |   9    |
| 54623   | 163.849  | 2014-10-16 12:01:09  |    43         |   9    |
| 54624   | 67.9257  | 2014-10-16 12:02:09  |    44         |   9    |
| 54625   | 315      | 2014-10-16 12:02:09  |    42         |   9    |
| 54626   | 0.699    | 2014-10-16 12:02:09  |    41         |   9    |
| 54627   | 67.9257  | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    46         |   9    |
| 54628   | 19.2308  | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    40         |   9    |
| 54629   | 11.207   | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    47         |   9    |
| 54630   | 118.743  | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    43         |   9    |
| 54631   | 292.5    | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    42         |   9    |
+---------+----------+----------------------+---------------+-------+
```

I need to get the  statistical mode or the `value_r` that repeats the most for a given `idparameter` and `idnode` in a given datime interval each hour. I have managed to get the mode when I set the datetime difference for 1 hour manually. However, when I try to group by hour or time difference it doesn't work and I end up with mode of the whole Start-End datetime and not group by hours.

So far this is my code:

```
select    value_r , date_r , max(counter_v) from
(SELECT   iddata,  value_r,date_r ,count( value_r ) counter_v 
FROM wsnca.data  dat
where dat.idnode=9 and dat.idparameter=42 and 
( dat.date_r between ('2014-10-16 12:00:00') and ('2014-10-16 13:00:00') )
group by value_r  
 order by counter_v  DESC) T;
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------------------+---------------+
| value_r   | date_r               | max(counter_v)|
+-----------+----------------------+--------------+
| 270       | 2014-10-16 12:03:09  |    7          |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

However, the result I'm looking for would be like this:

```
+----------+----------------------+---------------+
| value_r   | date_r               | max(counter_v)|
+-----------+----------------------+--------------+
| 270       | 2014-10-16 12:00:00  |    7          |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
| 90        | 2014-10-16 13:00:00  |    4          |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
| 45        | 2014-10-16 14:00:00  |    9          |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
| 180       | 2014-10-16 15:00:00  |    8          |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

As I said before, I don't know how to group that by one hour time interval and reading from the query round at the hour datetime as in the desired table.

I know I could do it in the PHP doing several queries but would prefer to do it in the one query.

Comment: Your outer `max(counter_v)` statement is returning only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can number the count for each `value_r` per hour starting with #1 for the highest count, #2 for the 2nd highest and so on and then only keep #1 rows, which will be the modes for each hour.

```
select date_hour, value_r, cnt from (
    select * , 
        @rowNum := IF(date_hour = @prevDateHour,@rowNum+1,1) rowNum,
        @prevDateHour := date_hour
    from (
        select value_r, hour(date_r) date_hour, count(*) cnt
        from wsnca.data dat
        where dat.idnode=9 and dat.idparameter=42
        group by value_r, hour(date_r)
    ) t1 order by date_hour, cnt desc
) t1 where rowNum = 1
```

Comment: I modify it to show the datetime and limit the date range in the where clause and 'date_year, date_month, date_day, ' in the order by clause. For small dates difference it works delightful but once the (EndDate-StartDate) gets larger the counts are miscalculated and the mode for same cases doesn't match the real one. Any guess why is that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndresJ try replacing the 2 instances of `hour(date_r)` with `DATE_FORMAT(date_r, '%Y-%m-%d %H')`

Answer (score 0):

change `group by value_r`  into `group by value_r, date_r` I think that should make it

**EDIT** Better Response for what you want to achieve

```
select    value_r , DATE_FORMAT(date_r, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as formatted_date, max(counter_v) from
(SELECT   iddata,  value_r,date_r ,count( value_r ) counter_v 
FROM wsnca.data  dat
where dat.idnode=9 and dat.idparameter=42 and 
( dat.date_r between ('2014-10-16 12:00:00') and ('2014-10-16 13:00:00') )
group by value_r, formatted_date
 order by counter_v  DESC) T
```

Comment: I get Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'formatted_date' in 'group statement' in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I understand your idea and I like it but when It doesn't execute in Workbench neither phpMyAdmin because of the formatted_date apparently. thnaks